# Reading comma seperated files

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a comma separated file
a,d,"f,h
and I need to read each of the entries ignoring any special characters ie "

I need to read these into variables for future processing.

I cannot use import-csv as this tries to interpret ".

The underlying issue is that I have mis formed files that are comma separated and need to be able to replace the faulty data with clean data.  faulty and clean being held in files such that and future extra issues can be added and the code dynamically handles the issue.

Once I can read the above then hopefully can use the same technique to read the source data, do the replace and save that back.

I have tried import-csv.
I can read the files and split on , but cannot store that into a named array

the solution will need to be able to read comma separated file, and not interpret the data between commas

1,3,"33,  will return 1   3    "33  {data after last comma is empty string} in a named array (file can contain headers if that helps).  I have control of one of the files so can reformat if required

I need something that will read a file with comma separation and store that into a variable that I can then loop through to use as a search and replace option on a second file

Once I have a solution for this I can take that into the final solution

```
1,"11,3,  will read as 
 line[0].col1 = 1
 line[0].col2 = "11
 line[0].col3 = 3
 line[0].col4 =
```

I would prefer each col to be named, but that isn't mandatory